# Adapt MFC dll for using in a C++/CLI wrapper

Tags: dll, mfc, c++-cli, wrapper

I have found out that it is essential to derive my base MFC class from `CWinApp` and use `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())` for every exported method! (if MFC is dyn. linked)

I would like also using an pointer to external native C++ object in MFC dll constr (I should use extension dll - but how work this with CLI???)

Have someone a good example for doing this kind of wrapping ?!

Thanks and greets,

leon22

Comment: What specific MFC features you need in your DLL? You may skip MFC altogether, or use static-linking. Is MFC DLL having some GUI/resources?

Comment: @ajay: Mainly I need the CString and I/O features of MFC (it's existing code) without GUI! I tried to statically link MFC but I get linker errors (which libs does I need in VS2008?) Thanks for your help!

Comment: For `CString` class you need NOT to link to MFC (either static or dynamic) - Just `#include<atlstr.h>`

Comment: I get: nafxcwd.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dllmain.obj)
1>nafxcwd.lib(afxmem.obj) : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(new.obj)
1>nafxcwd.lib(afxmem.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgdel.obj)
1>nafxcwd.lib(afxmem.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl operator delete[](void *)" (??_V@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(delete2.obj) if I use Windows libraries (no static/dyn. linking of MFC)

Comment: Put `LIBCMTD.lib` in "Ignore Libraries" linker settings

Comment: add to "Additional dependency"  -> Nafxcwd.lib Libcmtd.lib and ignore them with: add to "ignore specific library"  -> Nafxcwd.lib;Libcmtd.lib

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question or your problem is. You don't always need to use the AFX_MANAGE_STATE macro, it depends on the circumstances. What's a 'MFC dll constr' ? What does 'I should use extension dll' mean? (I know what an extension dll is, but what do you mean by 'should' in this context?) What does 'this kind of wrapping' mean?

Comment: I have an existing MFC dll and loading this with LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress into my C++/CLI wrapper! I need to destruct and load again this dll, but on second run I'm getting Access violation errors! When I construct the mfc object (loaded with GetProcAddress) an parameter is an pointer to another object (if you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30c674tx(v=vs.80).aspx I can't do this within a regular MFC dll -> extension dll) Hope you understand now my problem!